# How come this JQuery code returns nothing?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var newvalue = '<img class="youtube_replace youtube_canvas" data-code="Wn-_MyJV37E" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/Wn-_MyJV37E/0.jpg" />';

var abc = $('<div>' + newvalue + '</div>').find('*').each(function() {
}).html();

alert(abc);

</script>
```

I want abc to equal "newvalue".  But in my current code, abc is empty. Why?

This is what I truly want to do, but for example purposes, I left this blank above:

```
var whitelist = ['a','div','img', 'span'];
var abc = $('<div>' + newvalue + '</div>').find('*').each(function() {
    if($.inArray(this.nodeName.toLowerCase(), whitelist)==-1) {
        $(this).remove();
     }
}).html(); //abc is now sanitized!!!
```

Comment: You want the value of `abc` to be the same as the name of another variable - `newvalue`?

Comment: Yes. But of course I plan on doing things inside the function(){ }...right now it's just blank for example purposes.

Comment: manipulating html as strings is bad. Don't do it.

Comment: @Raynos no choice. I'm using node.js. I'm doing this in the backend.

Comment: @user847495 why the flying f*** would you use jQuery on the back end. That's the most stupid thing ever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking it down:

```
var abc = $('<div>' + newvalue + '</div>') //Creates a div with an img element inside it
         .find('*')   //retrieves the img element
         .each(function() {}) //iterates over the jQuery set (only one img element)
         .html();  //returns the HTML serialization of the img element
                   //which has no contents, so it is an empty string
```

You could call `.parent().html()`, which would retrieve the contents of the `div` you created.

In your second example, you would want `.end().html()` which would pop the internal jQuery stack and get you back to the top-most `div`.

Comment: Wait...why would I want .end() instead of .parent()? Of course...in real situations, the string would be much more than one image tag. So I should always use ".end" right???

Comment: `end` will work in all cases.  `parent` was the first thing that popped into my head because your first example only had one element.

Answer (score 1):

Do it like that (if you insist on getting HTML of element you just generated):

```
var abc = $('<div>' + newvalue + '</div>').html();
```

The problem is just incorrect mixing of different jQuery functions and callbacks.

**EDIT:**

The problem you have is that with `find('*')` you retrieve all the `<img>` tags (actually: one `<img>` tag) within `<div>`, but `<img>` tags **have no HTML inside them** (they have no other tags inside).

If you shorten your code to this:

```
var abc = $('<div>' + newvalue + '</div>').find('*').each(function() {
    /* your JS code here */
}).parent().html();
```

you will actually receive HTML of the whole `<img>` tag.

Comment: I need to perform actions inside the "each". Please read my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that when you do:

```
var abc = $('<div>' + newvalue + '</div>').find('*')
```

your jQuery object holds the `img` element, not the `div` element. So when you're calling `.html()`, you're getting the inner HTML of the image - which of course doesn't exist.

```
var abc = $('<div>' + newvalue + '</div>')
    .find('*')
    .each(function() {
        // stuff
    })
    .parent().html();
```

(but @Dennis got there first :). )